# Setting MS Access password at runtime in vb.net designer generated system

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, configuration, database-connection

I am developing a VB.NET update system for a volunteer organisation’s MS Access database. The database is protected by a password as it contains personal information. I have created the application using the VB designer. I need to be able to code the application so that, if the owner decides to change the MS Access password, they will have no need to come back to me to change the code and rebuild the solution. In other words, I do not want the password to be hard coded in the app.config file or the settings.designer.vb file. My code should not need to know the password as a simple call to one of the Fill functions can test any password entered by the user. My problem is that I have found no way to alter the connection string that is tested in the setttings.designer.vb code whenever the database is accessed. I am using Visual Studio 2017.

I have spent a long time searching the web for answers and have tried various solutions involving the configurationmanager without success. I am new to this area so I would be most grateful if anyone here can help.

Here is my latest attempt which still produces an invalid password error even though the third debug statement suggests that the connection string, including the password, has been correctly set.

```
  Public Sub UpdateConnString(connString As String)
Dim configFileMap As New ExeConfigurationFileMap()
Dim config As Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename)
Dim connStringName As String = "TestConnectionString"

Debug.Print("0 " + config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings(connStringName).ConnectionString)


config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings(connStringName).ConnectionString = connString
Debug.Print("1 " + config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings(connStringName).ConnectionString)

config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, True)
Debug.Print("2 " + config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings(connStringName).ConnectionString)
```

End Sub

Comment: I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-application-settings-dotnet)

Answer (score 0):

Just because a connection string is stored in the config file, you aren't required to use it as it is.  You can read in that default value and then edit it before using it, e.g.

```
Dim builder As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder(My.Settings.DefaultConnectionString)

builder.DataSource = dataSource

Dim connectionString = builder.ConnectionString
```

You can add or modify any part of a connection string you want that way at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, the code throws a compilation error - "DefaultConnectionString is not a member of My.Settings".

Fortunatley I have now managed to find a working solution:

```
'My.Settings.Item("TestConnectionString") = connectionString
```